# Match numerical values between two lists within an error range - Excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba

I have two lists of numerical values in Excel 2007. These values are instrument measurements and therefore have some amount of error associated with them. I need to see if the values from List 1 match any values from List 2 (within this error range) and then I need an indicator in list 1 indicating a value was matched. Ideally I would like this indicator to show the number of matched values from List 2.

The formula for the error margin is:

Error=[(Value List 1)-(Value List 2)/(Value List 2)]*1000000

The Error value we typically use is +/- 10

Example:

```
List 1  Matches List 2
100.0212    0   652.3269
514.2368    0   1036.1560
88.1842     0   88.3458
1036.1585   2   1036.1495
```

I have tried things like Vlookup but the tricky part I can't figure out how to incorporate the error margin. Any help or suggestions of things to look into would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry forgot a set or parenthesis in the formula. It should read:  Error={[(Value List 1)-(Value List 2)]/(Value List 2)}*1000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an array formula. Use the following, but after you paste the formula in, hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to save the cell. This will add braces to the left and right sides of the formula to indicate that Excel is treating it as an array formula. You can then autofill the rest of the column.

Assuming your example data is A1:C5, use this formula in B2:

```
{=SUM(IF(ABS(($C$2:$C$5-A2)/$C$2:$C$5*1000000)<10, 1, 0))}
```

Comment: @chemnerd1 glad to hear it! You can accept this answer by clicking the green checkmark to the left of it.